# master branch not listed in git branch command

Tags: git

I have been tracking a small project with git. I checkout a branch called 'samad'.
I have not committed changes for quite long. When I committed the changes and did git branch, I saw only the current branch I'm working on. Master branch was missing.
What might be the cause of it and what can I do possibly to bring it back.

Comment: But can somebody please explain what might be the cause? because initially it was there until just recently.

Comment: What does `git branch -a` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a new (empty) repo, no branch is created before the first commit.

If you ran `git checkout -b samad` before committing on `master`, the `master` branch is not created.

Comment: Yh..I can't remember whether I committed the changes before. A friend sent the project folder to me, but he wasn't using git on it. So I think as you said I probably didn't commit to the master before checking out that branch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You said you have no remote connected. So, simply create a new branch called `master` from this branch `samad`.

```
$ git checkout -b master
```

- How have you created this repo (`git init` or other)? If you created by `git init` then `master` (default branch) should be created automatically. I think, after `git init` you did checkout to `samad`. So, `master` branch is vanished.

**Note:** If you don't give any commit on `master` branch then it has no existence actually.

Comment: It still displays only the current branch. The project is not connected to any remote source.

Comment: @axiac sorry, I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already tried:

```
$ git fetch
```

Is cloning the project again an option?